# Customizing AlertDialog.Builder with multiple Buttons and EditTexts programmatically

Tags: android

The issue I've been running into is creating an AlertDialog popup that includes multiple EditTexts and Buttons, while also including the usual positive and negative buttons. With an additional '+' Button that would create another 'set' of EditTexts and Buttons below the previous one.
[A visual example.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX3jE.png)

I would also like to do this programmatically, if possible. The issue I've been running into is setView(), it seems like that method is meant to be used for only one sort of Button, EditText, or otherwise to show on the screen. But as I need more than one, and calling that method more than once just overrides the previous call, I've become stuck. The only thing I can find that might be it is ViewGroups but I haven't been able to find a way to work with it.

Any information on this would be immensely helpful!

Comment: set custom view of alert dialog and in that use recycler view that will control the rows containing edittext and button on the click of the add button.

Comment: Thank you, however that doesn't answer any question. Amanpreet Kaur gave an excellent point in the right direction, so this matter is fairly closed.